# Hetzner installimage and Gentoo, Are they frendly enough? Alternative installation?

Tags: linux, gentoo

So I'm trying to understand is there any way to install Gentoo via rescue system with hetzner installimage? Atm I'm getting something like this:

[image: Atm I'm getting something like this]

Debug comes here:

```
[19:49:15] # starting installimage on [ 5.9.123.83 ]
[19:49:15] -------------------------------------
[19:49:15] :   Hardware data:
[19:49:15] :   CPU1: Intel(R) Xeon(R) CPU E3-1245 V2 @ 3.40GHz (Cores 8)
[19:49:15] :   Memory:  15978 MB
[19:49:15] :   Disk /dev/sda: 3000 GB (=> 2794 GiB)
[19:49:15] :   Disk /dev/sdb: 3000 GB (=> 2794 GiB)
[19:49:15] :   Total capacity 5589 GiB with 2 Disks
[19:49:15] -------------------------------------
[19:49:15] # make clean config
[19:49:15] # executing setupfile
[19:49:15] # checking if the script is disabled
[19:49:15] # starting menu...
[19:49:18] # chosen image: [ custom ]
[19:49:18] # copy & create config...
[19:49:19] # Systype: System Product Name
[19:49:19] # Manufacturer: System manufacturer
[19:49:19] # starting mcedit...
[19:50:08] # validating vars...
[19:50:08] :   swap : 8192
[19:50:08] :   /boot : 512
[19:50:08] :   / : all
[19:50:08] :   Size of smallest drive is 3000592982016
[19:50:08] Calculated size of array is: 6001185964032
[19:50:08] checking if hdd sizes are within tolerance. min: 3000592982016 / max: 4050800525721
[19:50:08] DRIVE1 in range
[19:50:08] :   3000592982016
[19:50:08] DRIVE2 in range
[19:50:08] :   3000592982016
[19:50:08] :   check_dos_partitions
[19:50:08] # asking for confirmation...
[19:50:08] # Confirmation for drive /dev/sda accepted
[19:50:09] # Confirmation for drive /dev/sdb accepted
[19:50:09] # executing installfile...
[19:50:09] :   swap : 8192
[19:50:09] :   /boot : 512
[19:50:09] :   / : all
[19:50:09] :   check_dos_partitions
[19:50:09] # load debian specific functions...
[19:50:09] # Deleting partitions
[19:50:09] # Deleting partitions on /dev/sda
[19:50:11] # Deleting partitions on /dev/sdb
[19:50:12] # Test partition size
[19:50:12] :   using GPT (drive size bigger then 2TB or requested)
[19:50:12] :   check_dos_partitions
[19:50:12] # Creating partitions and /etc/fstab
[19:50:12] # Creating partitions on /dev/sda
[19:50:12] :   deactivate all dm-devices with dmraid and dmsetup
[19:50:12] :   no raid disks
[19:50:15] :   The operation has completed successfully.
[19:50:16] :   The operation has completed successfully.
[19:50:18] :   The operation has completed successfully.
[19:50:18] :   Creating BIOS_GRUB partition
[19:50:19] :   The operation has completed successfully.
[19:50:19] :   reread partition table after 5 seconds
[19:50:24] :   deactivate all dm-devices with dmraid and dmsetup
[19:50:24] :   no raid disks
[19:50:24] # Creating partitions on /dev/sdb
[19:50:24] :   deactivate all dm-devices with dmraid and dmsetup
[19:50:24] :   no raid disks
[19:50:27] :   The operation has completed successfully.
[19:50:28] :   The operation has completed successfully.
[19:50:29] :   The operation has completed successfully.
[19:50:29] :   Creating BIOS_GRUB partition
[19:50:30] :   The operation has completed successfully.
[19:50:30] :   reread partition table after 5 seconds
[19:50:35] :   deactivate all dm-devices with dmraid and dmsetup
[19:50:35] :   no raid disks
[19:50:36] # Creating software RAID level 0
[19:50:36] # create software raid array(s)
[19:50:36] :   Line is: "proc /proc proc defaults 0 0"
[19:50:36] :   Line is: "/dev/sdb1 none swap sw 0 0"
[19:50:36] Array RAID Level is: '0' -  -
[19:50:36] Array metadata is: '--metadata=1.2'
[19:50:36] :   Line is: "/dev/sdb2 /boot ext3 defaults 0 0"
[19:50:36] Array RAID Level is: '1' -  -
[19:50:36] Array metadata is: '--metadata=1.2'
[19:50:36] :   mdadm: /dev/sda2 appears to contain an ext2fs file system
[19:50:36] :   size=524288K  mtime=Sat Nov 30 19:43:40 2019
[19:50:36] :   mdadm: /dev/sdb2 appears to be part of a raid array:
[19:50:36] :   level=raid1 devices=2 ctime=Sat Nov 30 19:39:42 2019
[19:50:36] :   mdadm: partition table exists on /dev/sdb2 but will be lost or
[19:50:36] :   meaningless after creating array
[19:50:37] :   Line is: "/dev/sdb3 / ext4 defaults 0 0"
[19:50:37] Array RAID Level is: '0' -  -
[19:50:37] Array metadata is: '--metadata=1.2'
[19:50:37] :   mdadm: /dev/sda3 appears to contain an ext2fs file system
[19:50:37] :   size=2921351620K  mtime=Sat Nov 30 19:43:40 2019
[19:50:37] :   mdadm: /dev/sdb3 appears to be part of a raid array:
[19:50:37] :   level=raid1 devices=2 ctime=Sat Nov 30 19:39:44 2019
[19:50:37] :   mdadm: partition table exists on /dev/sdb3 but will be lost or
[19:50:37] :   meaningless after creating array
[19:50:42] # formatting  /dev/md/0  with  swap
[19:50:42] :   /dev/md/0: 10 bytes were erased at offset 0x00000ff6 (swap): 53 57 41 50 53 50 41 43 45 32
[19:50:43] :   Setting up swapspace version 1, size = 16 GiB (17160990720 bytes)
[19:50:43] :   no label, UUID=0338ac98-6b7f-448c-babe-b9d37242b268
[19:50:47] # formatting  /dev/md/1  with  ext3
[19:50:52] # formatting  /dev/md/2  with  ext4
[19:51:08] # Mounting partitions
[19:51:08] # Sync time via ntp
[19:51:08] :   Using standard Hetzner Online GmbH pubkey: /root/.oldroot/nfs/install/gpg/public-key.asc
[19:51:08] :   Using standard Hetzner Online GmbH pubkey: /root/.oldroot/nfs/install/gpg/public-key-2018.asc
[19:51:08] :   gpg: key 9E03E2BEB8F0F463: "Hetzner Online AG, RZ-Softwareentwicklung (Signing Key 2013) <info@hetzner.de>" not changed
[19:51:08] :   gpg: Total number processed: 1
[19:51:08] :   gpg:              unchanged: 1
[19:51:08] :   gpg: key 7030DBE4387333B3: "Hetzner Online GmbH image signing key <info@hetzner.com>" not changed
[19:51:08] :   gpg: Total number processed: 1
[19:51:08] :   gpg:              unchanged: 1
[19:51:08] # Validating image before starting extraction
[19:51:08] # Extracting image (local)
[19:51:25] # Setting up network config
[19:51:25] # setup network config
[19:51:25] # setting up /etc/network/interfaces
[19:51:25] # setting up /etc/udev/rules.d/70-persistent-net.rules
[19:51:25] mtab is already a symlink
[19:51:25] # Setting hostname
[19:51:25] # chroot: hostname custom
[19:51:25] # Generating new SSH keys
[19:51:25] skipping rsa1 key gen
[19:51:25] skipping dsa key gen
[19:51:25] skipping rsa key gen
[19:51:25] skipping ecdsa key gen
[19:51:25] skipping ed25519 key gen
[19:51:25] # Generating mdadm configuration
[19:51:25] # chroot: /usr/share/mdadm/mkconf > /etc/mdadm/mdadm.conf
[19:51:25] :   bash: /etc/mdadm/mdadm.conf: No such file or directory
[19:51:25] => FAILED
[19:51:25] :   report install.conf to rz-admin: 1312528
[19:51:26] :   report debug.txt to rz-admin:
[19:51:26] cleaning up
```

Maybe someone has faced the same error and would be so kind to share the solution. Or there should be another installation method? I would be happy if you shared the installation method.

Cheers!

Comment: You might have to report that one to Hetzner directly. As for other methods, of course you can just install it yourself as described in the wiki, e.g. https://wiki.gentoo.org/wiki/Complete_Handbook/Putting_the_minimal_environment_in_place#Preparing_the_stage_tarball

Answer (score 0):

I installed Gentoo on Hetzner vservers some years ago using [Hetzner - DokuWiki](https://wiki.hetzner.de/index.php/Gentoo_installieren/en) and later migrated them to Hetzner-cloudservers. You're just using the basic rescue image and start a standard gentoo installation from there.

If I had to make a new installation today I probably would give [asarubbo/gentoo-stage4](https://github.com/asarubbo/gentoo-stage4) a try.